# Pandas: Merging Multiple dataframes that are from two different lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists where multiple dataframes are present

```
df_lst_1 = [df_1,df_2,df_3]
df_lst_2 = [df_4,df_5,df_6]
```

Now I am trying to merge the dataframes but with a rider. That said, I want df_1 to be merged with df_4, df_2 to df_5. I.e. element wise merging. 
If I use the following code, the same is not being achieved.

```
df_m = [] 
for p in df_lst_1:
  for c in df_lst_2:
    df_merge = p.merge(c,how='inner',on='KUNNR')
    df_m.append(df_merge)
```

The above codes produces 9 dataframes. However, I need three 'merged' dataframes.

Any clue on this? How to use 'zip' or 'map' function here?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want `zip` and then `merge` in list comprehension:

```
df_m = [p.merge(c,how='inner',on='KUNNR') for p,c in zip(df_lst_1, df_lst_2)]
```

Or use loop solution:

```
df_m = [] 
for p,c in zip(df_lst_1, df_lst_2):
    df_merge = p.merge(c,how='inner',on='KUNNR')
    df_m.append(df_merge)
```